# Who should I trust to measure website speed?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, google-website-optimizer

My website indicates 2.5 seconds load time on Pingdom. But Google Analytics reports an avg load time of 25 seconds. (times 10!!!!!) Who should I trust?

Edit: I'm using wordpress CMS. should I use Ghost CMS? They advertise it as being 19 times faster than wordpress. In the time it takes for wordpress to process one request, Ghost has treated 19 requests.

Edit2: ubersuggest says my site loads under 3 seconds on desktop and mobile. I really don't know how to handle this. Google says my performance is low.

Comment: Pick Google Every time as they are the ones who decide your fate, if they think your site is slow, it is slow as far as they are concerned and your website won't rank as well. (which it is on a mobile with slow connection and CPU speed, pingdom assumes everyone has a leased line and a super computer)

Answer (score -1):

I Agree with Graham Ritchie.

may I just add that if you are **really** interested in measuring your websiste speed performance you may as well add a small JS snippet and measure it yourself on how **YOUR** users experiencing it.

Don't rely on any speed related performance machine.

What you should care about is how your users experiencing it.